# Shadow Mapping is faint

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to do OpenGL GLSL based shadow mapping. The trouble is that after I have finished rendering the shadow map, I am rendering the map to the screen to test whether the rendering works correctly or not i.e I am simply using the newly generated texture as a texture which I am mapping on to the screen. The expected result is that I will see the new texture. But instead, what i am seeing is a white area with the texture drawn but extremely faint. That is, if I tilt the screen at a certain angle only then I can see the faint outlines of the shadow map.

Can anyone tell me if I am doing anything wrong?

Here is relevant parts of my code :

```
     void Init_FBO() 
    { 
            //glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);  
        GLfloat border[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};  

        glGenTextures(1, &depthTex);  
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTex);  
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24,900,900, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);  
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);  
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);  
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);  
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);  
        glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, border);  
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);  
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LESS);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0); 

        glGenFramebuffers(1, &shadowFBO);  
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, shadowFBO);  
        glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);  
        glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);  
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTex, 0);  
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); // go back to the default framebuffer  
        // check FBO status 
        GLenum FBOstatus = glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER); 
        if(FBOstatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) 
        {
            printf("GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE failed, CANNOT use FBO\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Frame Buffer Done Succesfully\n");
        } 
    }




    void generateShadowTex()
    {
            //Calculate final ligting properties
        glm::vec4 a_f=light_ambient*mat_ambient;
        glm::vec4 d_f=light_diffuse*mat_diffuse;
        glm::vec4 s_f=light_specular*mat_specular;
        int counter=0;
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);    // need depth test to correctly draw 3D objects 
        glClearColor(0,0,0,1); 
        //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
        glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
        if(wframe)
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE); 
        else
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL); 


        glUseProgram(programObject);
        //Draw the stuff using Light Position as camera 
        //glutSwapBuffers();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,depthTex);
        glUseProgram(0);  

    }

void generateScene()
{
        //Calculate final ligting properties
    glm::vec4 a_f=light_ambient*mat_ambient;
    glm::vec4 d_f=light_diffuse*mat_diffuse;
    glm::vec4 s_f=light_specular*mat_specular;
    int counter=0;
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);    // need depth test to correctly draw 3D objects 
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

    //Draw the stuff using camera as camera position

    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glUseProgram(0);  

}



void display() 
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, shadowFBO); 
    generateShadowTex(); 
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); 
    generateScene(); 
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's *way* too much code to go through. Can you distill that down to a smaller functioning example?

Comment: @NicolBolas : Edited out irrelevant portions of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your depth texture is looking normally, depth covers range from near to far clip planes, you can set some reasonable clipping planes using `glFrustumf(...)`

Comment: Yes thank you that was the problem.....i had marked near plane as 0.01f and far plane as 10f ...changing it to 10f and 500f solved the problem...thank you very much Mr.Activation Cloud